# Use Port Binding Permissions on Windows

Tags: windows-7, bindings

This should be an easy one, but I can't find anything on it.

I want to use IIS Express with my local user account to bind to a port on my netbios name.  For example, http://computername:1315.  My local user account doesn't have permission to do this, but I have administrator access on the machine.

Anyone know how to grant permission to my local user account to bind to a port with my computer name instead of localhost?  This is on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course I find it as soon as I post this:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://computername:port/ user=username
```